# How to groupby and exclude data that is not matching?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following

```
data = [['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/about-us'],
['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/about-us/our-history'],
['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/our-brands'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1Life_Healthcare'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/0342975Z:US'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.1life_healthcare_inc.86b63a4a5977d4a3f91df5657d2c741b.html'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://www.1stconstitution.com/about-us/'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://www.1stconstitution.com/investor-relations/corporate-profile/'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Constitution_Bancorp'],
['1st Source','https://www.1stsource.com/about'],
['1st Source','https://www.1stsource.com/about/our-history-values-mission-and-vision'],
['1st Source','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Source'],]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "url"])
```

I wish to obtain data that does not include a Wikipedia link 'wikipedia.org', how can I go around?

I was trying with groupby, but groupby needs an aggregation hence impossible.

My expected output can be something like this: ['1-800-Flowers'] since only 1800 flower does not include a wikipedia link

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I just want get a list of 'name' that does not have a wikipedia link, perhaps a list will do if its the simpliest way to go around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.contains()` to check if Series element value contains expected string. Then using boolean indexing to select columns whose `url` column has expected string. At last to `set` operation to get names not containing expected string.

```py
wikipedia_names = df.loc[df['url'].str.contains('wikipedia.org'), 'name'].tolist()
names_not_in_wikipedia = list(set(df['name'].unique()) - set(wikipedia_names))
```

```
print(names_not_in_wikipedia)

['1-800-Flowers']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more solution to the problem at hand:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/about-us'],
['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/about-us/our-history'],
['1-800-Flowers','https://www.1800flowersinc.com/our-brands'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1Life_Healthcare'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/0342975Z:US'],
['1Life Healthcare','https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.1life_healthcare_inc.86b63a4a5977d4a3f91df5657d2c741b.html'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://www.1stconstitution.com/about-us/'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://www.1stconstitution.com/investor-relations/corporate-profile/'],
['1st Constitution Bancorp','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Constitution_Bancorp'],
['1st Source','https://www.1stsource.com/about'],
['1st Source','https://www.1stsource.com/about/our-history-values-mission-and-vision'],
['1st Source','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Source'],]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["name", "url"])
string = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
newdf = df[~df['url'].str.contains(string)]
print(newdf)
```